# Open link in a new window in ajax panel on server side

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have asked this question before, but got no answer that worked.

This is a buttonclick event that should initiate the download:

```
protected void btnDownload_Command1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = gvClients.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
    GetUserData usr = new GetUserData(item["id"].Text, Security.level.Agent, servermap);
    string file = usr.RetrieveContractPath();
    SendFileDownload(file);
}
```

One of the solutions that was offered was opening a link in a new window and have the window on page load initiate the download there with this piece of code:

```
protected void btnDownload_Command1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = gvClients.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
    GetUserData usr = new GetUserData(item["id"].Text, Security.level.Agent, servermap);
    string file = usr.RetrieveContractPath();
    // SendFileDownload(file); dont call it here , call it in the other window
    string url = "PopupFileDownload.aspx?file="+file;
    string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);

}
```

This did not work. I tried doing something similar since I am using the Telerik Ajax Panel

```
ajaxPanel.ResponseScripts.Add("window.open('DownLoadPopup.aspx?file='" + file + "'', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');");
```

But this also did not work. the command was executed with no effect.
How can I send a file to the user without sacrificing the Ajax panel?

Answer (score 0):

If your button's inside an ASP.NET Ajax UpdatePanel you could turn off the ajax for just the download button

```
ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(btnDownload);
```

Comment: I solved the problem a while ago with this solution: AjaxPanel1.registerstartupscripts.add(myscript);

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Telerik Ajax controls, you can use the following code to pop up a RadWindow.

Make sure you've got a RadScriptManager and a RadAjaxManager on your page before your RadAjaxPanel...

Then add a RadWindowManager inside your RadAjaxPanel like this...

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager runat="server" ID="rwm" Modal="true" Skin="Default" AutoSize="true" />
```

Then in your code, you can do this...

```
protected void btnDownload_Command1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  GridDataItem item = gvClients.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
  GetUserData usr = new GetUserData(item["id"].Text, Security.level.Agent, servermap);
  string file = usr.RetrieveContractPath();

  rwm.Windows.Clear();
  var rWin = new RadWindow();
  rWin.ID = "Name of my window";
  rWin.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/DownLoadPopup.aspx?file={0}", file);
  rWin.Width = Unit.Pixel(1000);
  rWin.Height = Unit.Pixel(600);
  rWin.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
  rwm.Windows.Add(rWin);
}
```

Adjust the path to your DownLoadPopup.aspx and the properties of the RadWindow as necessary.

Comment: Don't create a server object, it is not needed, create a blank RadWindow on the client by calling radopen(url, null), see here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening.html